# How to simple upload file in the Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How to simple upload file in the Google Cloud Storage JSON API from web browser using ajax call from java script.
I'm currently doing this

```
var Data={
    'async': true,
    'crossDomain': true,
    'url': 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/XXXXXX/o?uploadType=media&name=myfile',
    'type': 'POST',
    'contentType':'image/*',
    'content-length':65,
    'Authorization':"key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};
$.ajax(Data).done(function (response){
    console.log(response)  
});
```

gives 401 error code. How to solve this.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: "key=" looks like an API key, which isn't the same thing as an authorization token. You'll want to look at the [Google Cloud Platform Auth Guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication).